Spring ConditionalOnBean not working with ConfigurationProperties
I am trying to initialize a bean conditionally based on the existence of a set of ConfigurationProperties.
For context on the why, in reality I want to do it conditionally on some value in the ConfigurationProperties (using ConfitionalOnExpression or a custom Condition) but have left that out of this question for simplicity and am using ConditionalOnBean to illustrate the issue.
I have defined my ConfigurationProperties thus:
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprops")
public class MyProps {
    private final List<String> sources;
    
    public MyProps(List<String> sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
        System.out.println("MyProps constructor called with sources: " + sources);
    }

    public List<String> getSources() {
        return sources;
    }
}

The application:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class BeanOrderTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BeanOrderTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

And the dependent bean:
@ConditionalOnBean(MyProps.class)
@Component
public class MyBeanThatDependsOnMyProps {
    private final MyProps myProps;

    public MyBeanThatDependsOnMyProps(MyProps myProps) {
        this.myProps = myProps;
        System.out.println("Constructing MyBeanThatDependsOnMyProps," + myProps.getSources());
    }
}

I have some environment variables set in the form
MYPROPS_SOURCES_0=value1
MYPROPS_SOURCES_1=value2
...

What I observe when running the application is that MyBeanThatDependsOnMyProps never gets initialized. It seems the ConditionalOnBean is being evaluated before the ConfigurationProperties. The MyProps bean does get instantiated but I beleive only after the ConditionalOnBean has been evaluated as false.
How can I force the ConfigurationProperties bean to be instantiated first? I did try adding some Order annotation but to no avail. I also tried DependsOn, again that didn't work.
Any light anyone can shed on the Bean creation order with respect to ConfigurationProperties would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
Edit:
I enabled debug mode and on startup Spring confirms that no beans of type MyProps exist.
 MyBeanThatDependsOnMyProps:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.test.beanordertest.MyProps; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type com.test.beanordertest.MyProps (OnBeanCondition)



try adding a setter for sources in MyProps

You can add debug: true in your application.yml or application.properties. Then start your app and search for your bean. You will have the explained result of the conditional evaluation.

debug: true confirms the MyProps bean does not exist.

I added a setter for sources, no difference

The MyProp class is not a Spring component (bean) currently. It is not managed by Spring and does not exit in the application context. You have proofed it with debugging.
Solution
Add @Configuration property to the class.
This will cause Spring Boot to instantiate the bean as a singleton during application startup and make it available for dependency injection and for @ConditionalOnBean to match the condition.

It already marked with @Component.

MyProps is actually a bean without the @Configuration annotation. If I create another completely separate @Component annotated bean with ApplicationContext passed into it's constructor and add to it's constructor MyProps myProps = context.getBean(MyProps.class); it resolves fine and gets an instance of the MyProps bean.

The issue seems to be with the order in which the ConfigurationProperties beans are created- they are created after the @ConditionalOnBean is evaluated.
